# How to display information returned by ajax call in a tooltip

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, tooltip

I have created a JSP file which returns the information required from database. I have also written code which will make ajax call to this jsp file to retrieve the information. But I am not getting any good or free Tooltip libraries to know how to put this information into tooltip. Kindly suggest good and free libraries of tooltip in javascript( I am not good in jquery I know its powerful but I need to learn and change my whole code).

**Problem:** I need to show this tool tip contents on hovering the mouse on different options of listview. (each option of listview will have different infrormation) On moving mouse on each option should send an ajax call to the JSP page and get the intended calls back into the tooltip) I now the code of javascript to make ajax calls and get contents from JSP file the only problem is which tootip libraries to use and how to use it for each option of listview. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[qTIP](http://qrayg.com/learn/code/qtip) will do the trick. Get the library. Configure it for the tags that you need. The rest could follow like this:

1. Get the AJAX response
2. Use javascript to modify the title attribute. Something like

`document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('title', 'Ajax response here');`

The library would do the rest for you.

To circumvent the problem of the AJAX call you can use this check:

```
//on mouseover call for an AJAX function and check this
if(!document.getElemenyById(id).getAttribute){
    //the title is not set, use Ajax to retrive it an set it
    tooltip.init(); //this is crucial for the tooltip to work
}
```

Edit: Inside the library search for `var qTipTag = "a,label,input";` and change it to `var qTipTag = "li,a,label,input";`. This would start the tooltip engine for the tags you want.

you can see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/DarkThrone/gu6T2/5/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. So, once I have made an ajax call then document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('title', 'Ajax response here'); where id is the id of the select (i.e.listview) and instead of title should use option? Another thing where will I use the tooltip function to display the text? Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: The tooltip is instantiated on window.onload; you have to set the title attribute on the tag you want to display the tooltip.

Comment: Thank actually can you help in correcting the syntax           <html>
<body>

<select id=id1, tittle='r'>
  <option id=id2, tittle='b'>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>document.getElementById(id2).setAttribute(b, 'Ajax response here');
</body>
</html>    is this code correct? Since i want for each option an ajax call be made and contents in tooltip be displayed. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Here it's all the code http://jsfiddle.net/DarkThrone/gu6T2/ . You need niceforms http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/ qTip (as mentioned above) and this modifications to the code http://jsfiddle.net/DarkThrone/gu6T2/ that way all the code should work :) If you have any doubt you can post another question on stackoverflow or contact me via mi profile.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I have asked the question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716517/ajax-data-to-be-collected-in-tooltip    I am little bit confused that where should I save the contents of niceform. Do I need to include in the main web page or it can be saved backend or some other way is there? I will be able to make ajax calls to other domain but I am not able to reference the site. The domain doesn't allow the contents to be added. So what is safe way of including libraries or files.

Comment: @ DarkThrone Can you give a look to the following question related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727596/making-ajax-call-and-showing-contents-in-qtip