# Ajax data to be collected in tooltip

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, qtip

How should I proceed in achieving the following:
I need to get the data from another server which is a jsp page it has the data related to the information i want to show in tooltip. The code for this is working and I can make ajax call to get the response.

The concern is that I want the contents of qtip library to fit in the page since the page doesn't allow cross domain contents. If I will try to just reference the contents of qtip saved on my website(the domain is different from the page which I am using) it wont allow to do this. so is it fine embedding the contents in the main form or there is some other optimal way?

Similar question was asked:
[How to display information returned by ajax call in a tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706350/how-to-display-information-returned-by-ajax-call-in-a-tooltip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't reach cross domain via AJAX you can always uses an intermediary script (in your case Java) to output a buffer containing the information you want in the qTip.

1. Script calls `digest.jsp?params=someparameters`
2. digest.jsp fetchs the information from any domain it needs.
3. outputs the information in a buffer in XML o JSON
4. with javascript you parse the information an put it in the option attribute.

If it doesn't work for you nor you want to do it you can always relay in putting the information in each `title=""` attribute in each `option`.

Comment: Actually I dont have problem with ajax call. The problem is including the qtip.js in the webpage. I was already making ajax calls in other domain its working fine. e.g <script language="JavaScript" src="www.abc.com/qTip.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script> The web page is xyz.com domain and there I am incuding the above statement so as to include libraries.

Comment: The shouldn't been any problem with that. Are you writting the URL correctly? Can't you copy the script to the same xyz.com domain? It should be <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.abc.com/qTip.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script> with the 'http://' right after 'src="'

Comment: I have another question related to this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727596/making-ajax-call-and-showing-contents-in-qtip