# Making ajax call and showing contents in qtip

Tags: javascript, ajax, qtip

I am writing code for a dropdown list. The dropdown list is being populated from the data from the database. So I am making 2 ajax calls one is on event onmouseover to populate the contents of dropdown list and the other on selection of specific option making ajax call to bring related contents on the screen.

Now I want to make another ajax call to get the contents which can be populated on hovering over the specific option. The contents got from ajax call can be displayed in the small dialog box. For achieving this I have installed the qtip libraries.

**Problem**

I am not getting how the ajax call be made. Which even will be appropriate for achieving this? I know the qtip is loaded onload of the page. But since I want to make ajax call to get the contents of the message to be shown on hovering over the option. Any suggestions?

I have also read somewhere that you can't make more than 2 ajax calls at a time.

** The contents for the 3 ajax calls are different. And I have separate JSP files for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

```
$('.link').mouseover(function(){
    $.ajax(
        /* Retrieve de options for the select and fill each 
        title attribute with the information*/);
        url: "retrieveinfo.jsp",
        type: "GET",
        data: ({id : 'itemsId'}), //pass the data in JSON form
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){   //msg contains the html output or you could request XML (or JSON)
            $('#info').html(msg);
            NFinit();
            tooltip.init();
        }
});
```

That would make one AJAX call, populate the select and init niceforms and qtip.

Comment: Thanks for the solution... Now what I was doing is that I am modifying the JSP file to include the tittle which will be dynamically filled on each ajax call to that jsp file. Since the options of select statement I am adding through JSP file. Will it work now just by making normal calls to the JSP file and using NFinit();
            tooltip.init();

Comment: NFinit starts the Niceforme engine, that should be run only once (or whenever you add new form elements). tooltip.init() MUST be run everytime you add a title attribute to an HTML element. Think about this 2 cases only.

Comment: I was successfully able to add qtip and I can also see the messages thanks a lot for your help. But I haven't initialized NFinit() I was trying to load it with body... what will you suggest how to go with this.

Comment: If the input elements are style correctly then Niceforms was initialized successfully, otherwise check the niceforms.js and look for window.onload and move de function() that referes to the general onload with tooltip.init

Answer (score 1):

When you make your AJAX call to get the dropdown list content, you can also return the descriptions you want to display for each list item and affect them to the corresponding qtip.

The qtip will show onmouseover, and with the description you have set when populating your dropdown list.

Comment: Suppose we are in the case where the dropdown list has just been loaded. You can easily access the list of items that you want your user to see the corresponding description when hovering. Make a new AJAX call when dropdown population is complete that asks for the description of those items. Once you have it, fill the descriptions to the corresponding qtip (since you should have one qtip for each item) and you're done !  What part don't you understand ?